# user_filter vs base in restricting access to LDAP useres

Tags: ldap, gitlab

In the [`documentation`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html#using-an-ldap-filter-to-limit-access-to-your-gitlab-server) of Gitlab, it is given that, limit to LDAP user can be given by `base` and further by `user_filter`. So my questions are:

1. What is use of `base`
2. When to use `base` and when to use `user_filter` to limit LDAP users in gitlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base` specifies the starting point for the search, and its value is a distinguished name that exists in the database.

This differs from user_filter, which is a [search filter](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html), as in ldapsearch:

```
(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))
```

So GitLab will translate the `user_filter` directive into an `objectClass=user` ldap search filter.
But that will only apply to the LDAP object *below* the base tree specified in `base`.

The [GitLab LDAP configuration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/administration/auth/ldap.md#configuration) shows an example:

```
##
## Filter LDAP users
##
##   Format: RFC 4515 https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4515
##   Ex. (employeeType=developer)
##
##   Note: GitLab does not support omniauth-ldap's custom filter syntax.
##
##   Example for getting only specific users:
##   '(&(objectclass=user)(|(samaccountname=momo)(samaccountname=toto)))'
##
user_filter: ''
```

So check out the [RFC 4515](https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4515), but:
See also [issue 14464](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14464):

> GItLab automatically joins the filter you specify with the user's uid.
>   Leave off the uid part and just use user_filter:
>
> ```
> 'memberOf=CN=gitlab,DC=test,DC=com'
> ```

Comment: Is specifing `objectClass` is necessary in the `user_filter`? or can we directly give `user_filter= 'OU=group,DC=company,DC=local'`?

Comment: @DeepakRajana The latter: I have edited the answer to add some links and syntax illustration.

Comment: I was lead to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) page. So I got that doubt.

Comment: To deny a user we can declare `'(!(cn=username))'`. But how to deny by OU? `'(!(ou=projectmail))'` not working

Comment: @RajanaDeepak That looks like group filtering... which is an EE feature only (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap-ee.html)